# what is internal::state::Entry and where is it defined in mesos

Tags: c++, mesos, apache-zookeeper

I have tried the project `apache mesos` ZooKeeper part and I would like to know more about the usage of the `internal::state:Entry`
I can not see where it is defined or if it is a class?, could someone give more info about this part

Comment: I think it has something to do with the usage of google protobuf message handling, however I am not sure how to create this "class" or in what way it is really used in apache mesos

Comment: Take a look [here](https://github.com/apache/mesos/blob/81cd023eb9945a22c220edc966393dcfcdbce256/include/mesos/state/state.proto#L19-L24)

Comment: yes this is the .proto file which is used with a compiler to generate the Entry class - however how is it compiled, and what is Entry really used for in mesos?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Entry is a message defined by [include/mesos/state/state.proto](https://github.com/apache/mesos/blob/81cd023eb9945a22c220edc966393dcfcdbce256/include/mesos/state/state.proto#L19-L24). It's compiled with other protobuf messages by Make (make calls `protoc`). Make generate protobuf compiled C++ files. After build you can find `Entry` in [`build/include/mesos/state/state.pb.h`](https://github.com/apache/mesos/blob/e19d776057c64e443e71d6cd647a4c56aa87cb0f/src/Makefile.am#L286-L287) assuming you are following [the official build guide](https://mesos.apache.org/gettingstarted/).

Entry is used as a [Data Access Object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_access_object) and could be wrrapped by [`Variable`](https://github.com/apache/mesos/blob/81cd023eb9945a22c220edc966393dcfcdbce256/include/mesos/state/state.hpp) *"to force immutability"*.

Example usage of entry could be found in [src/state/leveldb.cpp](https://github.com/apache/mesos/blob/2e013890e47c30053b7b83cd205b432376589216/src/state/leveldb.cpp#L225-L273) or [src/state/in_memory.cpp](https://github.com/apache/mesos/blob/2e013890e47c30053b7b83cd205b432376589216/src/state/in_memory.cpp#L50-L66). As you can see it just wrapping butes to be saved with some name that allow finding it.

Comment: yes that was what I found out my self, however why would mesos use this giant of a message wrapper - what is the project gaining from using this ?

Comment: This is used to define interface to access to state store. Without protobuf developers will need to manually check if their changes to Entry are backward compatible. Protobuf gives it out of the box. And what's more important it also handle serialisation. [MESOS-5171](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MESOS-5171).

Comment: so it is used just to have the state handling? the protobuf is more than just state handling - not sure I understand fully

Comment: Not sure what "state handling" means in this context. It's used to define singe entry that will be saved in state store. Protobuf is just schema definition plus code generator for this schema.

Comment: the whole purpose of using ZooKeeper is to have it take care of distributed entities states, so why add extra state handling with protobuf?